# Close Button on Title Bar in MFC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

In Vc++ 6.0 Dialog Based MFC application:
I do not want my user close the window by pressing the button [X] in the top-right side of the window itself and also (Alt+F4). I want to display a messageBox ("Do you really want to close the application"); if the user clicks the OK button then the application has to close, else if user clicks the CANCEL button then the application must not be closed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement [`OnClose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/866bc849(VS.80).aspx) and only call the base class's `OnClose()` if you want to quit.

Answer (score 3):

Handle the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message and do something like this in it.

```
void CMyApp::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(nID == SC_CLOSE)
    {
        if(MessageBox(_T("Really"), _T("What"), MB_YESNO) == IDYES);
            //Do What you want here.
        else
            //Do something else
    }
    else
    {
        CDialog::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}
```

**Here is how to add WM_SYSCOMMAND Handler to your Code:**

Go to ClassView. Right click your dialog class if it is a dialog based application OR your mainframe class if it is a SDI/MDI Application. Click Properties.

In Properties Window, click on the Messages button. Scroll down to WM_SYSCOMMAND and on drop-down combo double-click to add the handler.

OR

You can do it manually as well by adding an entry in the message map. And adding declaration/definition in .h/.cpp respectively.

Comment: OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam) how to add this member funtion to my application. please i am new in VC++

Comment: this option is in .net but i am using vc++ 6.0 , in vc++ 6.0 if you right click on dialog class of dialog based application there is no option like properties. better i will try manually but sory to ask you , i dont know to how to add manually if give steps it is helpful to me.

Comment: Wow its working nice , Thank You Aamir final i got the result

Comment: In VC++ 6.0 you can do it through class wizard which comes up by pressing Ctrl + W (I think)