# Event Handler for Window Close button in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC application with Document - View architecture. I need to safely release and terminate a couple of resources in my program each time the user abruptly clicks the main Window's [X] close button. Currently, I have added some of this code to the Document class's destructor. However,I would prefer to catch the [X] button click in a seperate event handler, and do all the cleanup there. Can you please tell me how?

Should I override the handler for WM_CLOSE? If so, what class should the override go into?

Comment: Have you looked at "Close Button on Title Bar in MFC" found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163484/close-button-on-title-bar-in-mfc? Note that of the options provided, handling the WM_SYSCOMMAND message is perhaps the best option.

Comment: @BenKey, my application is an SDI. OnClose() is a member of what class? - so that I can override it

Comment: As I said, handling the WM_SYSCOMMAND message is perhaps the best option. This is done by overriding the OnSysCommand function in your App class. If you wish to use OnClose instead, it is, as the link provided in the question I linked to, a member of the CWnd class. Thus you would add it to your MainFrame class.

Comment: Why would you handle the press to the [x] buton, when the user does't finally close the application? It seams a bad idea for me. Maybe the document is changed. The user presses the [x] button. CMainFRame::OnClose is called. This will ask the documents that are changed, and the user may be asked if he want's to save. Now the user has the chance to press abort... and now? Only handle this freeing of resources when the application really closes. Either in ExitInstance or when the SDI document is closed...